# .NET Winforms ContextMenuStrip TextBox functions but Focus:Enter, Leave, Validating, Validated events never fire

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox, focus, contextmenustrip

The title says it all really.  I need to re-format the user entry after the textbox on a contextmenustrip loses focus - with the menu still open.  Event(s) never fire - all types of focus events.  Even after the menu closes.  I see other posts on this, but none seem to address the issue:  why don't these events fire?  I can enter or leave the TextBox by clicking, clicking away, tabbing, etc. still no events.  I have coded the .CausesValidation property to true and still no events.

Comment: Okay, I did find a post suggesting using the .LostFocus event, and that works.  Now I am REALLY frustrated.  That isn't an event that shows in the Visual Studio editor.  There are articles written on why that event shouldn't be used.  And yet... it functions while the lack of function in the orthodox usage remains a mystery.  Original question still stands - why don't the expected-use events work correctly?